# Mi base de datos MySQL dentro de mi contenedor de Docker no funciona, ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: mysql, flutter, docker

Acabo de instalar Docker para usarlo en una aplicación de Flutter. La instalación se ha hecho sin problemas, pero cuando intento correr el servidor (contenedor de Docker) 2 de las imágenes sí funcionan, pero la tercera no y es la base de datos de MySQL.

Mi sistema operativo es Windows 11, pero instalé WSL para poder usar comandos de Linux.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto el comando `docker-compose up` genera los siguientes mensajes en consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ingresar en Docker y mirar los Logs de MySQL muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado detener Docker por completo, eliminar el contenedor, cambiar los puertos e incluso buscar un archivo de sockets llamado "mysqld.sock", pero no existe. Ya me quedé sin ideas sobre qué hacer para resolver esto, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Deberías decir en qué sistema estás montando docker y dar algún detalle más. ¿Has revisado del log del contenedor mysql? Ahí podrás ver los mensajes generados y y por qué se detiene el contenedor.

Comment: Ya actualicé. Por lo de mi sistema operativo tengo Windows 11, pero descargué WSL para poder usar comandos de Linux.

Comment: Según uno de los mensajes de error el contenedor de mysql está intentando iniciar con el PID 62 y ya hay otro proceso cuyo PID debe ser el mismo. Probablemente en algún parámetro de configuración del contenedor estés forzando a que el sistema le asigne el PID 62?

Puedes publicar tu docker-compose para ver cómo tienes definidos los parámetros de los contenedores?
Has probado a iniciar primero el contenedor mysql y luego el resto?